# Where statements aren't working when the field I'm checking a text based field? (Pyodbc, Access)

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

I'm new to pyodbc, using it in my A-Level coursework.
I need to select data to do with a weapon from an access table based on its name my select query works for the id field but when I try to change it to check for WeaponName it gives me this error:

pyodbc.Error: ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1. (-3010) (SQLExecDirectW)')

This is my current code:

```py
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\FILE.accdb;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('select * from Weapons where WeaponName = LongSword')
   
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print (row)
```

When I change WeaponName = LonSword to ID = 1, then it works fine
Unsure as to why, sorry if this is the wrong formatting
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should wrap `LongWord` with single qoutes: `select * from Weapons where WeaponName = 'LongSword'`

Comment: That's worked, thanks a lot!